# How to use a Function of Switch/Case, if at all?

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

I have various products inside a database, each has its own price, the pattern to output a product price is:

`$product[i]["price"]`

I also have various "product types", which are manually defined in my code, each with index number that will relate to each product accordingly:

```
$type1="normal"
$type2="normal"
$type3="special"
...
```

I want to echo a message according to the price, and to the type, for each product.

My code pattern would be something like:

```
<p> lorem <?php echo function_output($product[1]["price"],$type1)?><p>
<p> ipsum <?php echo function_output($product[2]["price"],$type2)?><p>
<p> done <?php echo function_output($product[3]["price"],$type3)?><p>
```

(`lorem ipsum` stuff means I have some static content within the code).

Echoed line should be:

1. If price is `0` --> `<span class="free">Free</span>`
2. If price `> 0` --> **Echo `$` sign** + the price `$product[i]["price"]`
3. By default/fallback --> Don't echo anything
4. If the `type` is `special`, no matter what the price is --> Echo `It's
   special`

Intuitively it sounds like something to handle with `switch` command, but I really don't know how to use it the way I want, which probably involves a function. I only know the most basic form of `switch` command, I assume that my code should be something like:

```
$my_text = function_output($product[i]["price"],$type);

    switch ($product[i]["price"]) {

    case $product[i]["price"]=="0":
        $message = '<span class="free">Free</span>';
        break;

    case $product[i]["price"]>"0":
        $message = '$product[i]["price"]';
        break;

    case $type1="special":
        $message = 'It's Special';
        break;

    default:
        $message = 'no info';
    }
```

Yes, I know it's a complete mess, but no clue how to do this.

Edit:

For example, when `$product[i]["price"]=50` and `$type2="normal"`

`function_output($product[2]["price"],$type2)` should return: `$50`

Edit 2:

Basically I want the function to used in a similar way to following method:

```
function example( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'it's special',
        'default'    => 'nothing'
    );

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : $class_map[ 'default' ];
}
```

and then:

```
`example( $product[1]["price"],$type1)`
`example( $product[2]["price"],$type2)`
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming a price can never be less than zero.
So it seems that there are only three output options: "special", "free", or "price".

PHP's [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) might be more effective here:

```php
function function_output($price=0,$type='normal') {

  if ($type == "special") {
    $message = "It's Special";
  } elseif ($price == 0) {
    $message = '<span class="free">Free</span>';
  } else {
    $message = '$'.$price;
  }

  return $message;

}
```

But you can also use [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to evaluate multiple variables by passing it a value of `true`.
This might be useful if you're going to add more options in the future.

```
function function_output($price=0,$type='normal') {

    switch (true) {
      case $type == "special":
        $message = "It's Special";
        break;
      case $price == 0:
        $message = '<span class="free">Free</span>';
        break;
      default:
        $message = '$'.$price;
    }

    return $message;

}
```

Here's a [working example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yg32bv4j).

---

### Edit

Just for fun, a short version using nested [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operators:

```
function output($p=0,$t='normal') {
    return $t=='special'?"It's Special":($p==0?'<span class="free">Free</span>':'$'.$p);
}
```

[Working Example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yg326jvz)

Comment: can you elaborate how to fully use the code, including the `function_output($product[1]["price"],$type1)?>`?  I don't insist on using a `switch` at all, if there's a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using the function. Do you pass it a "price" and "type" and it returns a message to display?

Comment: your code says `($price=0,$type='normal')` but the whole rational that I want to use a function for is to have something universal, that will process any `price/type` combination, without predefining such combinations.

Comment: In PHP, you can define [default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). If you don't pass anything to the function, those will be the default values. You can remove them if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the switch statement wrong I know that for sure.

You can't use a switch like that. right now the switch statement is evaluating the value for $product[i]["price"] which will never be $product[i]["shipping"]=="0"

what I think you can do is:

```
switch (true) {

    case $product[i]["shipping"]=="0":
        $message = '<span class="free">Free</span>';
        break;

    case $product[i]["price"]>"0":
        $message = '$product[i]["price"]';
        break;

    case $type1="special":
        $message = 'It's Special';
        break;

    default:
        $message = 'no info';
    }
```

But I personally don't see an issue using if statements in this instance with so little cases

Comment: sorry, I had a typo there, `shipping` should be `price`